# File "E:\python\lib\re.py", line 229, in finditer return _compile(pattern, flags).finditer(string) TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, sublimetext3, scikit-image

I am working with the skimage.feature.greycomatrix to calculate the image's GLCM(Gray-Level Co-occurrence Matrix),   but when I use:

```
from skimage.feature import greycomatrix
```

in `python 3.6.4` shell - it works. *[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQtgc.jpg)*

**But when I use it in my sublime Text 3, then
it will report an error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Martin Ma\Desktop\every day python\test\GLCM\main.py", line 80, in <module>
    from skimage.feature import greycomatrix
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\skimage\feature\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .peak import peak_local_max
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\skimage\feature\peak.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ..segmentation import relabel_sequential
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\skimage\segmentation\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .random_walker_segmentation import random_walker
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\skimage\segmentation\random_walker_segmentation.py", line 43, in <module>
    from ..filters import rank_order
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\skimage\filters\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .edges import (sobel, sobel_h, sobel_v,
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\skimage\filters\edges.py", line 17, in <module>
    from ..restoration.uft import laplacian
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\skimage\restoration\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .inpaint import inpaint_biharmonic
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\skimage\restoration\inpaint.py", line 9, in <module>
    from ..measure import label
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\skimage\measure\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from ._regionprops import regionprops, perimeter
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\skimage\measure\_regionprops.py", line 645, in <module>
    _install_properties_docs()
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\skimage\measure\_regionprops.py", line 632, in _install_properties_docs
    prop_doc = _parse_docs()
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\skimage\measure\_regionprops.py", line 625, in _parse_docs
    doc, flags=re.DOTALL)
  File "E:\python\lib\re.py", line 229, in finditer
    return _compile(pattern, flags).finditer(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

*[(See picture of Sublime Text error)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wd4Lg.jpg)*

**Can anyone tell me why this happens and how I can solve it?**

My code:

```
from skimage.feature import greycomatrix
import numpy as np 

image=np.array([[1,1,5,6,8],
                [0,0,5,7,1],
                [4,0,0,1,2],
                [8,5,1,2,5]],dtype=np.uint8)
#levels=256   image   this test is 9
result=greycomatrix(image,[1],[0,np.pi/4,np.pi/2,3*np.pi/4],levels=9)
print(result[:, :, 0, 0])
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0G9R.jpg)

Comment: Unless you include your code, I'm afraid no one can help you.

Comment: Are you sure it's executing the correct version of python when it runs?

Comment: Are you running Python with the `-OO` flag? If you are, remove the flag.

Comment: @ Gautam J. Thanks a lot.I had put my code and the error image in my question!

Comment: @ user2357112 ，thanks a lot .I have modify my python3.sublime_build and it works.but I dont know why remove the -OO  flag ?

Comment: @ OdatNurd,thanks a lot

Comment: Fascinating! @user2357112, could you make an answer with links as to why this helps? Is there anything we can change about the skimage code so that this works with -OO?

Comment: @Juan: Answer posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were running Python with the [`-OO`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-oo) flag, which discards docstrings, replacing them with `None`. `skimage.measure._regionprops` [includes code](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/v0.14.0/skimage/measure/_regionprops.py#L619) that, during initialization, parses the docstring of one function to set the docstrings of a bunch of other functions. This fails when docstrings have been discarded. Running Python without the `-OO` flag avoids the issue.

It looks like similar issues may have been encountered and fixed in other parts of the scikit-image codebase; I see a few places that already check for docstrings being set to `None`, such as in [`skimage.io`](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/v0.14.0/skimage/io/__init__.py#L62). To make `skimage.measure._regionprops` compatible with `-OO`, a similar check for a `None` docstring would have to be added to that module. `_install_properties_docs` does a bit more than just docstring handling, though, so we can't just skip the whole thing if we don't have docstrings.

Comment: Fascinating!  thank you so much!@user2357112 ,  you are great and deeper in python,but I am only a python recruit,  I mean I could only use it to write some programs,  but when I meet some errors in python ,I dont know how to handle it by myself. so I would find it in StackOverFlow ,that's great. sometimes I wonder I could handle it by myself.  however I dont have enough knowledge to handle it .so do you have any suggestions or some books or some links  which are used for this ,thanks a lot.